# CS50 pset4 recover: only two files are recovered

Tags: c, cs50

I am currently working on pset4 recover.c. My code complies correctly, but when I run it, only two files are outputted (000.jpg & 001.jpg), which I believe there should be 50 files. I'm not sure why this happens. The images that print out are crystal clear--there is nothing wrong with the first two images. Would anyone have any insight on this? Here is my code below:

Side note: I've seen examples where the condition in the 'while' loop is 'while(fread(buffer, 1, 512, card_ptr) == 1)', where mine is set at 'while(true)'. I've tried changing the while condition to this and didn't see any change.

```
typedef uint8_t BYTE;

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

//check for eligible command-line arguments

    if (argc != 2)
    {
        printf("Usage: ./recover image\n");
        return 1;
    }

    char *infile = argv[1];

    FILE *card_ptr = fopen(infile, "r");
    if (card_ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Could not open file\n");
        return 1;
    }
//declare variables

    BYTE buffer[512];

    FILE *outfileptr = NULL;

    char filename[8];

    int jpeg_found = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        outfileptr = fread(buffer, 1, 512, card_ptr);
        bool jpgheader = (buffer [0] == 0xff && buffer[1] == 0xd8 && buffer[2] == 0xff && (buffer[3] & 0xf0) == 0xe0);
        int counter = 0;

        if (jpgheader && outfileptr != NULL)
        {
            fclose(outfileptr);
            counter ++;
        }

        if (jpgheader)
        {
            sprintf(filename, "%03i.jpg", counter);
            outfileptr = fopen(filename, "w");
        }
        if (outfileptr != NULL)
        {//write to
            fwrite(buffer, 1, 512, outfileptr);
        }
    }

    fclose(outfileptr);
    fclose(card_ptr);
}
```

Comment: `outfileptr = fread(...)` -- That looks very wrong. `fread` returns the number of bytes read, not a file pointer. What's more, this will corrupt the pointer to your current output file.

Comment: `while (true)` is okay, but you must `break` (or `return` or `goto`)  out of it some time. You could so so on reading zero bytes ...

Comment: Also, while it is usually good to make variables tightly scoped, your `counter` needs to be global. The way it works now, you only ever write `000.jpg` and `001.jpg`, possible overwriting their contents..

Comment: Thank you! I rewrote my counter variable to be initialized outside the while loop, and it solved my problem.